# реализация KNN python

Tags: python, ооп, классы

Пытаюсь реализовать метод ближайших соседей в python . Не могу понять в чем ошибка.

```
class MyKnnModel:
   
    def __init__(self, n_neighbors=3):
        self._k = n_neighbors

    def fit(self, X, y):
        self._X = X.copy()
        self._y = y.copy()
        return self
        
    def get_dist_matrix(self, X):
        """Генерирует матрицу расстояний D, элемент D[i,j] которой равен расстоянию между i-ой строкой матрицы X и j-ой строкой обучающей выборки признаков"""
        D=np.sqrt(((self._X[:,None,:] - self._X)**2).sum(axis=2))
        return D
              
    def get_neighbors(self, X):
        """Возвращает индексы k-ближайших соседей из обучающей выборки для каждой строки матрицы X."""
        
        dist=self.get_dist_matrix(X)
        neighbors=dist.argsort(axis=0)[:self._k].T
        return neighbors
    
    def predict(self, X):
   
        raise NotImplementedError
        

class MyKnnRegressor(MyKnnModel):
    """Регрессор, основанный на k-ближайших соседях."""
   
    def predict(self, X):
        neighbors = self.get_neighbors(X)
        y_pred = np.zeros(len(neighbors))
        
        for i in range(len(neighbors)):
            label = self._y[neighbors[i]]
            pred_y_i = np.mean(label)
            y_pred[i] = pred_y_i

        return y_pred
    
class MyKnnClassifier(MyKnnModel):    
  
    def predict(self, X):
        neighbors = self.get_neighbors(X)
        y_pred = np.zeros(len(neighbors))
        
        for i in range(len(neighbors)):
            label = self._y[neighbors[i]]
            pred_y_i = np.argmax(np.bincount(label))
            y_pred[i] = pred_y_i
        
        return y_pred
```

Проверка

```
X_train = np.array([[-1.21345377, -1.54174037],
                    [ 1.50513153, -0.23814019],
                    [ 1.15413283, -0.04085176],
                    [ 1.6248147 ,  0.11745924],
                    [ 0.41190036,  0.16466746],
                    [-0.56861959, -0.18716551],
                    [-0.20204102, -1.46273951],
                    [ 0.79519222,  0.31601044],
                    [-0.47799507,  0.55453979],
                    [-0.10039373, -0.70497529]])
y_train_reg = np.array([1.9619973 , 1.52385422, 1.1548556 , 1.62905478, 0.44359585,
                        0.59863108, 1.47662705, 0.85568292, 0.73211588, 0.71208782])
y_train_clf = np.array([0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0])
X_test = np.array([[-1.54277153, -0.12430863],
                   [ 1.15146114,  0.08724635],
                   [-0.99423371, -0.77970332],
                   [-0.16547913,  0.79244826],
                   [-0.42078791,  0.81083815]])
model = MyKnnRegressor(3)
model.fit(X_train, y_train_reg)
dist_matrix = model.get_dist_matrix(X_test)
neighbors = model.get_neighbors(X_test)

assert np.isclose(model.predict(X_test),
                  np.array([1.09758142, 1.21319777, 1.0909054 , 0.5914476 , 0.5914476 ])).all(), \
       "Значения прогнозов не совпадают!"

assert (neighbors == np.array([[5, 8, 0],
                               [2, 7, 3],
                               [5, 0, 9],
                               [8, 4, 5],
                               [8, 5, 4]])).all(), \
       "Ближайшие соседи не совпадают!"

assert np.isclose(dist_matrix, np.array([[1.45518484, 3.05002798, 2.69819536, 3.17679937, 1.97591735,
                                          0.97617774, 1.89445388, 2.37906607, 1.26276842, 1.55487218],
                                         [2.8716581 , 0.48058209, 0.12812597, 0.47431678, 0.74360216,
                                          1.74183225, 2.05777167, 0.42339172, 1.69513737, 1.4814708 ],
                                         [0.79294256, 2.55736529, 2.27186717, 2.76844997, 1.69382679,
                                          0.72955359, 1.04599603, 2.09824541, 1.43063168, 0.8969583 ],
                                         [2.55864953, 1.96291939, 1.56069364, 1.91331183, 0.85292192,
                                          1.05932307, 2.25548413, 1.07232571, 0.39276794, 1.49883735],
                                         [2.48252792, 2.19306207, 1.79046112, 2.1599223 , 1.05399541,
                                          1.00889321, 2.28407653, 1.31280697, 0.26260523, 1.54930398]])).all(), \
       "Матрицы расстояний не совпадают!"

print('Ошибок не обнаружено!')

Вылезает - operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10,) (5,) , думаю, что связано с self
```

Answer (score 2):

Тем, кто так составляет вопрос так и хочется спросить, "Что и откуда у вас *вылезает*"?  У вас же перед глазами есть вывод интерпретатора, где однозначно указано, в какой именно строчке программы у вас *это* "вылезает". И причина ошибки тоже однозначно написана в этом "вылезшем". И означает она, что вы делаете операцию, у которой оба параметра должны быть одинаковой размерности, а вы задаете их разной.

И если бы вы просто проанализировали ваше "вылезшее", то поняли-бы, что в
операторе `np.isclose` у вас первый параметр формируется с помощью
метода `model.predict` в виде numpy-массива из 10 элементов, а второй параметр -  массив, который вы формируете сами -  содержит всего 5 значений.  Поэтому выполнить операцию ПОЭЛЕМЕНТНОГО сравнения массивов невозможно.

Вот и исправляйте это несоответствие.